# How do I rig a model with no arms and floating hands?

Tags: modeling, rigging, armature, bones, eevee-render-engine

I'm currently making a low poly character model and I'm not quite done with it yet, but when I do finish it I'm planning on rigging it. This character, however, has no arms and has floating hands. (Think Rayman.) I'm wondering if it would be possible to rig a character like this, and how I could go about doing this? This is my first time 3D modeling, by the way.[image: The Reference Image Of My Model]

Answer (score 1):

These disconnected arms don't impact the rigging much, it actually make it simpler. You could just use Rigify the usual way. It's just that the arms par of the rig will have no mesh to deform, and that's OK.

It is actually interesting to keep the arms in the rigging: when you want the hands to have a natural movement, you will animate with invisible arms thanks to the FK, you won't see the arms but you will "feel" them through the hands movement. And when you need nothing realistic or want to go stylized in your animation, just switch to IK and have fun.