# How do I rig a character with no Limbs?

Tags: animation, rigging

i need help rigging a character that has no arms or legs, i'm a bit of an amature in blender so i need some assistance from the professionals, thank you :)[image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/248665/how-do-i-rig-a-model-with-no-arms-and-floating-hands?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

You can use a classical armature except the arm bones, for example, won't control any vertex, but they will make the movement of the hands more correct:

[image]

In order to parent, if your soldier character is made of only one object: Give the good names to your bones (like *Hand.L* for the left hand), select the character, shift select the armature, parent *With Empty Groups*, then select the object, switch to *Edit* mode, select the vertices you want and assign them to the vertex group that has the same name as the bone that is supposed to control it.

Comment: man, i was so long looking on your picture and wasn't sure whether the bones are now displayed in green in pose mode....until i realized, you painted the bones manually!!!!! :D

Comment: hey this is Blender 4!!

Comment: and even coding skills has this man....you are insane!!!!!